# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast with chars and strings

Tags: c

I keep getting segmentation faults on this code, I'm learning C at the moment.. Can anyone help me out?

Error location:

```
char *m;
char *as = concat("helloworld", buf);
*m = sha1(as);                               <<<<<< as
printf("%s\n", m);
free(as);
```

The concat function (not mine, used for joining 2 strings):

```
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(len1+len2+1);//+1 for the zero-terminator
    //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result+len1, s2, len2+1);//+1 to copy the null-terminator
    return result;
}
```

The sha1 function:

```
char *sha1( char *val ){

   int msg_length = strlen( val );
   int hash_length = gcry_md_get_algo_dlen( GCRY_MD_SHA1 );
   unsigned char hash[ hash_length ];
   char *out = (char *) malloc( sizeof(char) * ((hash_length*2)+1) );
   char *p = out;
   gcry_md_hash_buffer( GCRY_MD_SHA1, hash, val, msg_length );
   int i;
   for ( i = 0; i < hash_length; i++, p += 2 ) {
      snprintf ( p, 3, "%02x", hash[i] );
   }
   return out;
}
```

Since I'm asking, what do they mean with:

```
 //in real code you would check for errors in malloc here
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: *m = sha1(as);  Where is m defined ?

Comment: `char *m;` is above that, copy failure

Comment: sha1 is returning a char* and m is already a char* so m = sha1(as) without the * shall do better work

Comment: Does this question have 3 questions? (the warning, the seg-fault + the explanation of malloc error checking) You really should try to stick to one or, at the very least, put them all together.

Comment: Sorry I sometimes forget this is not a forum.. Will think of it next time, the warning is the reason for the segmentation fault

Comment: @Marco for the question about checking malloc. Its required since the memory allocation might fail (for any reasons, but an example could be if your system do not have some anymore)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was in *m:

```
char *m = sha1("helloworld");    < OK
*m = sha1("helloworld");         < fail
```

Answer (score 1):

`sha1()` returns `char *`, so you need to change `*m = sha1(as);` to `m = sha(as);`. `*m` is of type `char`, not `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

change `*m = sha1(as);` to `m = sha1(as);`. `*m` is a `char` value not a `char *`.

Now second question:

*in real code you would check for errors in malloc here*

is all about error handling where you need to check returned pointer from `malloc` against `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = sha1(as);
```

`*m` dereferences the pointer, it means the character under the pointer.

As for `malloc`, if it cannot allocate memory if will return a `NULL` pointer. You should check for that.